# Installing programs in git bash?

Tags: windows, installation, git, git-bash

I'm running git bash on windows and I'd like to install some of the linux tools I'm familiar with but apt-get, yum, etc don't appear to work. How can I install programs in git bash?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific: Which Widows? What programs? Does sudo apt-get update/upgrade work as expected?

Comment: Windows 8. Normal bash programs like grep, nano, etc. No, `sudo apt-get` doesn't work any more than `apt-get`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to install programs within `git bash`. It's not an operating system.

Comment: It isn't possible, if you want to install Linux applications, you want to use WSL which only supports Windows 10 obviously

Comment: Or use cygwin if it's not windows 10.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) or [scoop](http://scoop.sh/) which will allow you to install software from the command line and they do work on git bash. But if you really want linux software you can install windows 10 then the [windows linux subsystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide) which does allow you to use `apt-get` if you choose Ubuntu over Opensuse.

Comment: The windows linux subsystem you suggested form Windows 10 works great. Thanks!

Comment: WSL is nice.. but comes with all sorts of issues of its own. copy and paste not working is the start of a long, bumpy road..

Answer (score 4):

Git Bash does not seem to have a package manager.

When using Cygwin or MobaXterm (and there may be more derivatives), you actually can use apt-get like it's ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the binary exe file from sites that provide windows exe binaries of linux commands and add it to the Git binaries folder (under the path /c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin). Check this out:

Example:

To install **wget** and I quote from https://gist.github.com/evanwill/0207876c3243bbb6863e65ec5dc3f058:

> - Download the lastest wget binary for windows from [eternallybored](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/)    (they are available as a zip with
>     documentation, or just an exe)
> - If you downloaded the zip, extract all (if windows built in zip utility gives an error, use 7-zip).
> - Rename the file `wget64.exe` to `wget.exe` if necessary.
> - Move `wget.exe` to your `Git\mingw64\bin\`.

To download **nano**:

> - Download the Nano binary from Nano [win32-support](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/win32-support/) page. You just need the `.exe` file, which is named `nano-git-0d9a7347243.exe` (as of
>     this writing).
> - Rename the file to `nano.exe`, and copy to the `mingw64\bin` directory.
> - This version of Nano will not work with Git Bash alone, but can be invoked using `winpty`, for example, `winpty nano test.txt`.
>
> *As of 2018, recent versions of Git Bash include Nano, so this is
>   unnecessary! Just be sure to choose Nano as your default editor when
>   installing Git for Windows.*

You can also consider using [cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) as a unix-like systems emulator on Windows, where a wide variety of binaries can be included upon installation, and can be added later on.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 1):

**Option #1** - Combination of Git SDK and Git-SCM

First, go Download the [Git For Windows SDK](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/releases/tag/git-sdk-1.0.8), then transfer all the binaries in C:/git-SDK-64/usr/bin to C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin and then transfer all the files in /etc. Lastly download [WGET](https://gist.github.com/evanwill/0207876c3243bbb6863e65ec5dc3f058) seperately as mentioned in the above answer.

**NOTE:** This method is incredibly dodgy and **not recomended** for multiple reasons. This is only useful if you want to (kinda) get a Linux Enviroment.

**Option #2**

Just download [Git For Windows SDK](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/releases/tag/git-sdk-1.0.8) and use that as an almost complete Linux Enviroment.
e
**OR**

[Use the Windows Subsystem For Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) a much more rounded up version of a Linux Enviroment than just a shell. This is the best option as it is a complete Linux Enviroment and well mainained by Microsoft

**Option #3**

The last option is to download [MSYSY2 packages](https://packages.msys2.org/queue). Then unzip it using preferably [PeaZip](https://peazip.github.io/) as other Unzipping softwares such as 7-zip don't support the same format. After extraction manually place in files in your Git installation Directory

Comment: You should post each option separately so that they may be voted upon separately